# For Each loop to delete all tables deletes one of two tables

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to delete all the tables on a slide.
There are two tables on page 5, but the code deletes the first table only.

```vb
Sub deleteTable()
    Dim p5 As Slide, shp As Shape
    Set p5 = ActivePresentation.Slides(5)
    p5.Select
    For Each shp In p5.Shapes
        If shp.Type = 19 Then 
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: Try and have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34897508/18247317, else I would change `If shp.Type = 19 Then` to `If shp.Type = msoTable Then` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17434336/18247317)

Comment: Its because you are deleting from a collection which causes all items following the deleted item to renumber. The control variable for the for each loop won't be aware of the deletion so will appear to skip over a row after each deletion.  To delete from a collection in a loop you need to get the collection count and then iterate down (for index = count to 1 step -1).

Comment: hi @Bradipo , thanks for your reply. I did the modification, but it still would only delete one table.

Comment: @qiao, freeflow's comment added one piece of information that I missed (appearing in fact in the posts I linked for you)

Comment: One other suggestion: remove p5.select 
You don't need to select the slide to do this and using select unnecessarily can slow things down or cause the the code to fail in some situations.